# How to download media content from XML feeds

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, xml

For the past few years, I've been using Newsboat for to follow RSS feeds with text, and a web-based RSS reader for feeds with images/videos/gifs. However, I'd like to bring all of my RSS feeds over to the command line.

I'm trying to write a script to extract & download media content (jpgs, gifs & mp4s) from a list of XML feeds to my drive using Terminal. So far I've tried this: https://github.com/lingnand/rss-image-download and this https://gist.github.com/snipe/4758106 . Neither of these scripts worked for me. I've read through this post https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139683/how-to-download-images-from-an-xml-feed-using-terminal though it's not quite the same.

I know that I need to use a command like curl to extract the media. I already have a file that lists my XML sources. I'll probably need to create an additional file to keep track of the feeds that have already been downloaded. My knowledge of writing scripts in Bash is basic at best and I'm not sure how I would need to parse the RSS feeds to do this.